# Bulgarian permanent residence and citizenship

Tags: resident-permit, eu-citizens, bulgaria, bulgarian-citizens

I married a Bulgarian girl, and I will apply for visa D and apply for family residence there. Can i know exactly how many years I need to get permanent residence and citizenship? I searched a lot but I found various articles. Some says family permanent residence after 2 years and other articles says after 5 years. Please if anyone have specific information about that or trusted reference, that will be great.

Answer (score 3):

Several official references out there ([UK Governmental website](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/living-in-bulgaria), [PDF document from Europa.eu](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjUjs7l5ovMAhVCORoKHblUAes4ChAWCCkwAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fec.europa.eu%2Fdgs%2Fhome-affairs%2Fwhat-we-do%2Fnetworks%2Feuropean_migration_network%2Freports%2Fdocs%2Fad-hoc-queries%2Ffamily-reunification%2F274_emn_ad-hoc_query_marriage_-_entry_rights__residence_22nov2010_wider_dissemination_en.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFOFiCo99zVLH96-KUcWozUQSmnBw&bvm=bv.119408272,d.d2s) and [Bulgarian Governmental website](http://eu.mvr.bg/en/How_change/eucitizens.htm)) seem to suggest that in order to apply for a permanent Bulgarian residence you have to have resided in Bulgaria for five years. Now, [the Bulgarian governmental website](http://eu.mvr.bg/en/How_change/eucitizens.htm) also states a particular condition which applies to foreigners who married a Bulgarian national:

> - foreign nationals who married either a Bulgarian national, or a foreign national residing permanently in Bulgaria since two years;

The way I understand this is that **if you married a Bulgarian national you can apply for permanent residence straight away**. You can also do so if you married a foreigner who's been residing permanently in Bulgaria for the past two years.

This is also echoed by [the PDF I linked from Europa.eu](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjUjs7l5ovMAhVCORoKHblUAes4ChAWCCkwAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fec.europa.eu%2Fdgs%2Fhome-affairs%2Fwhat-we-do%2Fnetworks%2Feuropean_migration_network%2Freports%2Fdocs%2Fad-hoc-queries%2Ffamily-reunification%2F274_emn_ad-hoc_query_marriage_-_entry_rights__residence_22nov2010_wider_dissemination_en.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFOFiCo99zVLH96-KUcWozUQSmnBw&bvm=bv.119408272,d.d2s), which states:

> 1. a) b) Yes, citizens or persons granted permanent residence in the Republic of Bulgaria can bring non-EU spouses. People resident in the
>      Bulgaria who are Bulgarian citizens by birth or who have acquired citizenship are all permitted to bring the following family members to
>      the Bulgaria:
>
>    1. a spouse;

Ultimately, if you still have doubts, the best way to go about this is to contact your local Bulgarian diplomatic mission and ask them. Personally, that's what I would do.